# smarty inside javascript

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

i put smarty code in js/jquery function but doesn't work and i see blank page! How To Fix This?

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("#IsGroupGallery").click(function() {
      {literal} {if $photos} $.lightbox(["{"\", \""|implode:$photos}"]); {/if}{/literal}
      return false;
    });

  });
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

Comment: Which Smarty version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner literal tags are backwards, and you are attempting to nest additional literals *inside* a {literal} tag (which obviously will not work because {literal} tells Smarty to leave the contents unchanged.) It should probably look like this instead:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("#lbgallery").click(function() {
      {/literal} {if $photos} $.lightbox(["{"\", \""|implode:$photos}"]); {/if}{literal}
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
{/literal}
```

Notice the two literal tags inside your outer literal tags have been reversed. You need to first end the literal, then re-start it again, otherwise the contents of the inner {literal} tags will also be treated as literal, and not evaluated - and that just doesn't make sense for what you are trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Smarty3 parses `{ if` as literal string ("auto literals"). So whenever `{` is surrounded by whitespace, it is ignored by Smarty3.

If that - for whatever reason - doesn't help, or you're stuck with Smarty 2, please Note that `{literal}` tags don't nest.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("#lbgallery").click(function() {
{/literal}
      {if $photos} $.lightbox(["{"\", \""|implode:$photos}"]); {/if}
{literal}
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
{/literal}
```